# Collision detection in paper.js

Tags: paperjs

I'm implementing a simple game in Paper.js for educational purposes. The game features some bacteria, whose bodies are `Path.RoundedRectangle`s. I'm trying to write a function `colliding(roundedRect1, roundedRect2)` using Paper's `PathItem.intersects(item)` method, but it returns true every time!

Before I scrap this tactic and write my own collision detection, I'm wondering if anybody has successfully used Paper's builtin `intersects` for this. Thanks!

Comment: Wow, an agar.io clone? :D

Comment: sorta (but with rounded rects!). will hopefully be controlling some bacteria w neural nets.

Comment: I used the getDistance() function implemented thusly: `circle.getDistance(radius*2)`. If this returns `true` then we have a collision! However this will obviously only work for circles.

Comment: You might want to post more detailed example code. I provided a simple example that works but your example is probably more complex and there might be something else going on. But with no details I can't provide a better answer.

Comment: What you are describing is inbuilt with [Pixi.js](http://www.pixijs.com/) which is far more suitable framework for what you are trying to achieve. This [Tutorial](https://github.com/kittykatattack/learningPixi) even describes how to get set up and underway guiding you through developing a simple game, and even includes [Collision Detection](https://github.com/kittykatattack/learningPixi#collision-detection). Paper.js is the better framework for drawing and creating shapes. Once the shapes/images are created, Pixi.js is better at showcasing or working with them, including animations and game de

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use the code `path.intersects(otherPath)` which returns true or false.

You can take a look at a simple example that shows intersect works here:

[Simple Paper Sketch showing intersect function](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#S/lZLBboMwDIZfJcoFKiHU0tJDp532AlV32GHdIYBVKrKYOtl2mPbui4FWlLKJKlLk6P9ifVbyLY16B7mRzxW4vJSRzLHg8958KhLksBaPwsCX2OLRuHAxn0fCb7OHDsjQXQFLBpYt0CGQn5GdL5U5aAi5cdTcPneqe9xWuTLuwb6KRMpkQ8XWEVbwhBrJ3wgIimCQvRwLV/osaTRuxkjYMmktb0ZYcbjqwmnyp0nypzH5TKu8CgbpRX/UPmXB9A/7NYfru+xpkj2N239AMAiv5PcmR2NRQ6zxELZP5DWBrK9s2Aw94/b/YnTB+sv/1oxAVTUPbuXm9e3nFw==).